# Addition rule for mutually exclusive events

Tags: probability

Why does the addition rule not work here?

$$P(\text{win this week}) = 0.5$$
$$P(\text{win next week}) = 0.5$$

They are mutually exclusive, and you can only win once (although it is possible that neither occurs). What is the probability that either occurs?

$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$ clearly does not give the correct answer, unless you are guaranteed to win (but that is not the case here).

Comment: Why do you think that P=1 does not give the correct answer and why do you think one can only win once? What kind of game or lottery is this?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.

Comment: P=1 cannot be correct. I have 50% chance of winning this week, and a 50% chance of winning next week. They are mutually exclusive since you can only win once. There is a decent chance that I won't win at all, so P=1 cannot be correct. I'm missing something.

Comment: Try to draw a Venn diagram. $A$ has to cover half of the whole area, and $B$ also has to cover half of the whole area. But their intersection should be an empty set.

Comment: Intersection would imply that both events occur, but you can only win once. There is some probability that you will win.

Comment: Another way of thinking about this: There are only four events: You win neither; you win 1st; you win 2nd; you win both. Their sum should equal to 1 and the last one is equal to zero. What is the probability that you win neither?

Comment: @Fuzz You have to put `@user` into the comment if you that a user gets notified that you answered to the users comment. besides that, can you describe the lottery/game that you are talking about?

Comment: @MattiP. I think you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: It seems that you aren't **allowed** to win twice.

Answer (score 1):

The question makes sense in a scenario as under.

A school (say) gives a prize to some student every fortnight, but if someone has got the prize in the first fortnight, she is **not considered** for the prize in the second fortnight. Then, for any particular student,

P(doesn't get any prize that month) = $0.5\times0.5 = 0.25$

P(doesn't get a prize the $1^{st}$ fortnight, but does in the $2^{nd}) = 0.5\times 0.5 = 0.25$

P(gets a prize in the first fortnight) = $0.5$

As it must, the probabilities add up to $1$

---

### Generalization added

Let probabilities of getting prize in first and second fortnight be $a$ and $b$ respectively, then

P(don't get any prize) = $(1-a)(1-b) = 1-a-b+ab$

P(get prize only first fortnight) = $a$

P(don't get $1^{st}$ fortnight, get in $2^{nd} = (1-a)b = b-ab$

Adding together, we get $1$, as we must

Comment: Okay that makes sense. $P(A' \cap B')$ gives the probability that it doesn't occur, so subtracting this from 1 gives the probability that it does occur.

Comment: So what about this problem causes the addition rule for mutually exclusive events to break? Is it because the complements are not mutually exclusive?

Comment: I think I get it now. The second probability is .25 since it requires an initial loss. How would one describe this scenario? Is it a conditional probability? If so, are they still mutually exclusive?

Comment: $P(A) = 0.5, P(B|A^c) = 0.5, P(B|A) = 0$

Answer (score 0):

I think you confuse **Independency** & **Exclusiveness**. These are seems to be Mutually independent, not exclusive. Or there is some other information about game or lottery as @miracle173 noticed.

**By informations of comments:**

So, **Yes,** the probability of wins in whole $2$ weeks is $1$. But if you have problem to be winner surely, you can suppose some scenario in which you don't:

Suppose you randomly pick a number in $[0,1]$ and if it's a irrational number in $(0,1/2)$ you become the winner of the first week, and if it's a irrational number in $(1/2,1)$ you would be the winner of the next week. So you win by probability of $1$, **but not surely,** you lose if you be a **infinitely** bad luck rational picker!

Comment: They are mutually exclusive but not independent. If E1 occurs, E2 cannot occur.

Comment: Exclusiveness, in this case, means you can't win in both weeks, is it the case?

Comment: Correct, you can win one week or no weeks, but not both weeks.